# download using rsync and extract using gunzip, and put all together into a pipe

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, rsync, gunzip

I have "gz" files that I am downloading using "rsync". Then, as these files are compressed, I need to extract them using gunzip (I am open to any other alternative for gunzip). I want to put all these commands together into a pipe to have something like that `rsync file | gunzip`

My original command is the following:
`awk -F "\t" '$5~/^(reference genome|representative genome)$/ {sub("ftp", "rsync", $20); b=$20"/*genomic.fna.gz"; print b" viral/." }' assembly_summary_viral.txt  | xargs -l1 rsync --copy-links --times --recursive --verbose --exclude="*rna*" --exclude="*cds*"`

It looks a little bit complicated, but it's downloading the files that I need, and there is no problem with it. I added `| gunzip` However the extraction of the compressed files is not working, and it's only downloading them.

Any suggestion?

Comment: A pipe redirects stdout to the stdin of the command following the pipe. I'm assuming that the stdout of your rsync command is not something that `gunzip` can use. I'm also wondering how that `xargs rsync` is working. Nifty.

Comment: I am not an expert in shell commands... But, I found the script xargs rsync over the internet when I was trying to pipe the output of the awk, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

A pipe takes the stdout of the left command and sends it to the stdin of the right command. Here we have to take the stdout of `rsync` and pipe to the stdin of `gunzip`.

`rsync` doesn't really output much without the `-v` flag so you'll have to add that. It will now spit out to `stdout` something like the following:

```
>rsync -rv ./ ../viral
sending incremental file list
file1
file2
file3
test1_2/
test1_2/file1
test1_2/file2

sent 393 bytes  received 123 bytes  1,032.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

We can pipe that to `awk` first to grab only the file path/name and prepend `viral/` to the front of it so that it gunzips the files that you just rsync'd TO (instead of the ones FROM which you rsync'd):

```
rsync -rv ./ ../viral | awk '!NF{endFileList=1} NR>1 && endFileList!=1{print "../viral/"$0}'
```

Now we have rsync and awk spitting out a list of filenames that are being sent to the TO directory. Now we need to get `gunzip` to process that list. Unfortunately, `gunzip` can't take in a list of files. If you send `gunzip` something to it's `stdin` it will assume that the stream is a gzipped stream and will attempt to gunzip it.

Instead we'll employ that `xargs` method you have above take the stdin and feed it into `gunzip` as the parameter (filename) that it needs:

```
 rsync -rv ./ ../viral | awk '!NF{endFileList=1} NR>1 && endFileList!=1{print "../viral/"$0}' | xargs -l1 gunzip
```

Most likely you will have to tweak this a bit to insure you are gunzipping the right files (either your FROM location files or your TO location files). This gets trickier if you are rsyncing to a remote computer of SSH, obviously. Not sure if that can just be piped.